# Is “to bottom line” actually gaining traction?

Tags: word-usage, neologisms

The following extract from   [grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/idiom/bottom-line/#:%7E:text=The%20bottom%20line%20is%20an,profit%20or%20took%20a%20loss.) suggests that the idiomatic expression “bottom line” is mainly used as a noun but it is increasingly also being used as a verb:

> By the 1980s, the term the bottom line took on a figurative sense to mean the most important facet of a situation or the outcome of a situation. The bottom line is a noun, though increasingly it is being used as a verb as in bottom line me, a request to leave out the details of an explanation and skip to the important part.

I could not  find “bottom line” defined  as a verb in dictionaries and this usage sounds quite unusual to me.

Is there evidence of its verbal usage in any English dialect, especially the American one?

Comment: I'm more worried about "gaining traction".

Comment: Isn't Grammarist evidence of its use as a verb? What kind of evidence do you want? A quick Google finds examples in forums but do you want edited text or something more formal? Or are you specifically fact-checking Grammarist?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's still very rare. There are only about 12 results in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) that use it as a verb. (I searched for `bottom LINE` and grouped by PoS.) Five of those hits are Chris Matthews on NBC saying something like "let's bottom line this". The rest of the hits are somewhat randomly scattered between 1997 and 2011.